# Meteor React Komposer: Execute Component Constructor AFTER ready subscription

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a React Component **Post**:

```
export class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     this.state = this.props;
  }
  ...
}
```

, which I compose with

```
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
```

import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import Post from '../components/post.jsx';

```
function composer(props, onData) {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('post', props.postId);

  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const data = {
      ready: true,
      posts: Posts.findOne(props.postId).fetch()
    }
    onData(null, data);
  } else {
    onData(null, {ready: false});
  }
}

export default composeWithTracker(composer)(Post);
```

. As given in the *Post Component* I want to put some properties in the state of the component, but the **constructor will be executed before I get the data from the composer**!

**How do I wait until the data is send and then put my `props` into the `state`?**

Isn't this what the *React Kompose* should do? BTW I am using Version `1.~` to get `composeWithTracker`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `componentWillReceiveProps` to get new properties and set as component state. This function will run whenever there are new properties passed to component:

```
export class Post extends React.Component {
  // ...
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      ...nextProps,
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!